# Extern auth services with Web API - can't get the sample to work

Tags: google-oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I can't get the sample [External Authentication Services with Web API(C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services) to work with Google.  I created a project by following the instructions.  However, I noticed that my project created a slightly different code in Startup.ConfigureAuth() method.

```
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "<valid client id here>",
            ClientSecret = "<valid secret here>",
        });
```

The code in the sample does not have the initialization part but without it the code will not even compile.

When I run the app I get the option on the Log In screen to use Google as a service to log in.  I'm then taken to Google's site and asked to allow my app to use my info.  The app's name appears to be correct so I have to assume that ClientId/ClientSecret provided above are correct.  However, when I click "Allow" button I'm taken back to the Log In page instead of the Register page as illustrated in the example.

---

Has anyone managed to make the sample work with Google authentication?  If yes, could you please share workarounds, if any.

---

Thanks.

Comment: personally i used Googles .net client library.  But you should be redirected to what ever you set the redirect uri to in the Google Developers console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the source of the problem with a help of a post on this site.  Unfortunately I lost the link to the post.  Anyway, the solution is to make sure that Google+ APIs are enabled in Google Console for the project - they are not enabled by default.  The details can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/07/02/changes-to-google-oauth-2-0-and-updates-in-google-middleware-for-3-0-0-rc-release.aspx) (as suggested by the post).